# JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is a caused by a JSON formatting error in Zend framework while using group by

Tags: mysql, json, zend-framework, datatable, warnings

Please help me. I am stuck with one DataTable warning like "DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is a caused by a JSON formatting error." in zend framework with PHP, JSON encode.

This warning only happens when the table is empty, But This problem is only coming when I use group keyword in sql query, If I do not use group keyword then it gives only one record from the table, but table have more records also. When I use the following query the output becomes, to show all records only the table have data, if not datatable warning will be shown.
// sql query (models/table/product.php)

```
    public function fetchAllProductItems() {
$oSelect = $this->select()
                ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                ->from(array("p" => "products","b" => "bid"), ('*'))
                ->joinLeft(array("b" => "bid"), "b.product_id=p.product_id", array('bid_id','bid_amount'))
                ->joinInner(array("e" => "employees"), "e.employee_id=p.employee_id",array('ename'))
                ->where("p.verified = ?", "Yes")
                ->where("p.sold_out = ?", "No")
                ->group('p.product_id')
                ->having("p.sale_end_date >= ?", date("Y-m-d"));
        return $oSelect;
    }
```

//JSON encode (Modules/sell/controllers/apicontroller)

```
public function getProductsAction()
{

     $oProductModel = new Application_Model_Db_Table_Products();
     $oSelect = $oProductModel->fetchAllProductItems();
     echo Zend_Json::encode($this->_helper->DataTables($oSelect, array('product_id','e.ename as employee_name','name', 'brand', 'conditions', 'about','image_path', 'reserved_price', 'Max(b.bid_amount) as amount')));

}
```

The below query will show only one record, if more than one records are having in the table. If the table is empty then I will come "No Data available in table message will come".

// sql query (models/table/product.php)

```
 $oSelect = $this->select()
                ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                ->from(array("p" => "products","b" => "bid"), ('*'))
                ->joinLeft(array("b" => "bid"), "b.product_id=p.product_id", array('bid_id','bid_amount'))
                ->joinInner(array("e" => "employees"), "e.employee_id=p.employee_id",array('ename'))
                ->where("p.verified = ?", "Yes")
                ->where("p.sold_out = ?", "No")

                ->where("p.sale_end_date >= ?", date("Y-m-d"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to add the "ViewJsonStrategy" to your module's config and mark your ViewModel as “terminal”.

Something like that:

```
public function getProductsAction()
{   
     $oProductModel = new Application_Model_Db_Table_Products();
     $oSelect = $oProductModel->fetchAllProductItems();
     //ViewModel requires one array
     $data = ['result'=>$this->_helper->DataTables($oSelect, ...)];
     $view = new ViewModel($data)->setTerminal(true);
}
```

I have one example at GitHub that may helps:

https://github.com/fmacias/SMSDispatcher

Link to official documentation:
https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html .

In the other hand, if you want to deserialize the object as JSON and echo this output you should set the headers before.

With plain PHP:

```
header('Content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode($someData);
```

With Zend something like that:

```
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('ContentType','application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo $yourJson;
```